# I'm receiving error message jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'sys_data' is undefined

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and Jinja and I'm trying to figure out an example application I found [here](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/raspberry-pi-system-information-web-application-with-python-and-flask/).
Its a fairly old post (2016) so I don't really want to ask a question there.

From what I can see sys_data seems to be defined on the fourth line in my extract.
The strange part is, to try and diagnose what is going on I even commented out all references to sys_data with "#" and I still get the error.  The article seems reasonably well thought out so I don't think he could have missed an undefined variable type error.
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I have cleared the browser cache and restarted the dev application server.  My python version is 3.7.3

```
def index():
sys_data = {"current_time": '',"machine_name": ''}
try:
    sys_data['current_time'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y , %I : %M : %S %p")
    sys_data['machine_name'] =  platform.node()
    cpu_genric_info = cpu_generic_details()
    disk_usage_info = disk_usage_list()
    running_process_info = running_process_list()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    return render_template("status.html", title='Raspberry Pi - System Information',
    sys_data = sys_data,
    cpu_genric_info = cpu_genric_info,
    disk_usage_info= disk_usage_info,
    running_process_info = running_process_info)
```

Here is the full code from the example.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime
import platform
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/status')
def index():
    sys_data = {"current_time": '',"machine_name": ''}
    try:
        sys_data['current_time'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y , %I : %M : %S %p")
        sys_data['machine_name'] =  platform.node()
        cpu_genric_info = cpu_generic_details()
        disk_usage_info = disk_usage_list()
        running_process_info = running_process_list()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return render_template("status.html", title='Raspberry Pi - System Information',
        sys_data = sys_data,
        cpu_genric_info = cpu_genric_info,
        disk_usage_info= disk_usage_info,
        running_process_info = running_process_info)

def cpu_generic_details():
    try:
        items = [s.split('\t: ') for s in subprocess.check_output(["cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq "], shell=True).splitlines()]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return items

@app.context_processor
def boot_info():
    item = {'start_time': 'Na','running_since':'Na'}
    try:
        item['running_duration'] = subprocess.check_output(['uptime -p'], shell=True)
        item['start_time'] = subprocess.check_output(['uptime -s'], shell=True)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return dict(boot_info = item)

@app.context_processor
def memory_usage_info():
    try:
        item = {'total': 0,'used': 0,'available': 0 }
        item['total']=  subprocess.check_output(["free -m -t | awk 'NR==2' | awk '{print $2'}"], shell=True)
        item['used']=  subprocess.check_output(["free -m -t | awk 'NR==3' | awk '{print $3'}"], shell=True)
        item['available']= int(item['total'])- int(item['used'])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return dict(memory_usage_info = item)

@app.context_processor
def os_name():
    os_info = subprocess.check_output("cat /etc/*-release | grep PRETTY_NAME | cut -d= -f2", shell=True).replace('\"', '')
    return dict(os_name=os_info)

@app.context_processor
def cpu_usage_info():
    item = {'in_use': 0}
    try:
        item['in_use'] = subprocess.check_output("top -b -n2 | grep 'Cpu(s)'|tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2 + $4 }'", shell=True)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return dict(cpu_usage_info = item)

@app.context_processor
def cpu_processor_count():
    proc_info = subprocess.check_output("nproc", shell=True).replace('\"', '')
    return dict(cpu_processor_count=proc_info)

@app.context_processor
def cpu_core_frequency():
    core_frequency = subprocess.check_output("vcgencmd get_config arm_freq | cut -d= -f2", shell=True).replace('\"', '')
    return dict(cpu_core_frequency=core_frequency)

@app.context_processor
def cpu_core_volt():
    core_volt = subprocess.check_output("vcgencmd measure_volts| cut -d= -f2", shell=True).replace('\"', '')
    return dict(cpu_core_volt=core_volt)

@app.context_processor
def cpu_temperature():
    cpuInfo = {'temperature': 0, 'color': 'white'}
    try:
        cpuTemp = float(subprocess.check_output(["vcgencmd measure_temp"], shell=True).split('=')[1].split('\'')[0])
        cpuInfo['temperature']=cpuTemp
        if cpuTemp > 40 and cpuTemp < 50:
            cpuInfo['color'] = 'orange'
        elif cpuTemp > 50:
             cpuInfo['color'] = 'red'
        return cpuInfo
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return dict(cpu_temperature=cpuInfo)

def disk_usage_list():
    try:
        items = [s.split() for s in subprocess.check_output(['df', '-h'], universal_newlines=True).splitlines()]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return items[1:]

def running_process_list():
    try:
        items = [s.split() for s in subprocess.check_output(["ps -Ao user,pid,pcpu,pmem,comm,lstart --sort=-pcpu"], shell=True).splitlines()]
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        return items[1:]

@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def short_date(a,b,c):
        return u'{0}{1}, {2}'.format(a, b,c)
    return dict(short_date=short_date)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the full text of the error.log if that helps at all.

```
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.883874 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214] [2021-07-28 21:20:59,870] ERROR in app: Exception on /status/ [POST]
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.884407 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.884557 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.884683 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.884804 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.884924 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885042 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885161 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885334 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885512 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     raise value
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885632 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885754 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885871 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.885993 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.886110 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/var/www/html/app.py", line 64, in status
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.886274 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     return render_template('status.html')
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.886902 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887115 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     context, ctx.app)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887295 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887604 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     rv = template.render(context)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887747 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887872 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.887993 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888113 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888293 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888602 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888731 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888848 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.888956 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/var/www/html/templates/status.html", line 50, in top-level template code
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.889067 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     {{sys_data.machine_name}}
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.889178 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.889393 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214]     return getattr(obj, attribute)
[Wed Jul 28 21:20:59.889520 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 392] [remote 180.181.85.2:50214] jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'sys_data' is undefined
```

Comment: Do indents in the code snippet are correct?

Comment: I have been through the indents again and can't see any problem.  I did remove a couple of lines that had just a single space but that didn't make any difference.  I have added the full error log and the full program to the question so see if that helps pin point the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You abuse the `finally:` statement.
   If something went wrong, you don't want to return rendered template because some variables could be undefined.
2. I've created a small example based on your code so you could get a clue how it works.
   Structure

```sh
.
└── flaskr
    ├── app.py
    └── templates
        └── status.html
```

`flaskr/app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from datetime import datetime
import platform

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/status')
def index():
    sys_data = {"current_time": '', "machine_name": ''}
    try:
        sys_data['current_time'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y , %I : %M : %S %p")
        sys_data['machine_name'] = platform.node()
        return render_template("status.html", title='Raspberry Pi - System Information',
                               sys_data=sys_data,
                               )
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return Response(str(ex.with_traceback()), 500)


@app.route('/status-error')
def status_error():
    sys_data = {"current_time": '', "machine_name": ''}
    try:
        sys_data['current_time'] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y , %I : %M : %S %p")
        sys_data['machine_name'] = platform.node()
        # Throw exceptioin
        assert 0
        return render_template("status.html", title='Raspberry Pi - System Information',
                               sys_data=sys_data,
                               )

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return Response(str(ex.with_traceback()), 500)


@app.context_processor
def context_function():
    return {"ctx_var": "some_context_value"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`flaskr/templates/status.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
sys_data.machine_name: {{sys_data.machine_name}}
<br>
context variable: {{ctx_var}}
<br>
it will be added automatically in the namespace,
so you dont need to pass it to the template explicitly.
</body>
</html>
```

Try to trigger the following entry points and see how it works.

- `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status`
- `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status-error`
  Both are GET methods.

P.S. A nice tool to work with API https://www.postman.com/.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I'll work through that tomorrow.  I'm using a headless Raspberry Pi in a terminal window so no dev environment.  I'll have to come up with something better for testing :) I think the actual problem is in the html.  I removed the references to sys_data and the error moved to the next variable.

Comment: If you add this `app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")`, you can use your laptop/pc to test API. It will be available from any of the computers in your local network.

Comment: I have been testing with flask run --host 0.0.0.0 and that seems to work ok.  I can view the page on my laptop.

Comment: I have also tried your code and it returns this which appears to be what is expected "sys_data.machine_name: ROVER1
context variable: some_context_value
it will be added automatically in the namespace, so you dont need to pass it to the template explicitly."  I'm not sure how to use this example to fix the problems with the example code I'm trying to use for status details of the PI.  I didn't write it but now I'm trying to debug it :)

Comment: Good luck, ping me if you'll have any questions.